# Getting: Invalid component 'use' when trying to use SVG

Tags: lightning-aura-components, svg-icon

Im trying to follow the split view examples in https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/split-view/
but i cannot save the component.

I'm getting an Invalid component 'use' for every svg snippet.

Example snippet :

```
<svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#side_list"></use>
                </svg>
```

Any idea if i'm doing something wrong ? I just want to implement a split-view in a custom aura component and this is the only example i could find.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `svg` with `lightning-icon`.

```html
<lightning-icon icon-name="standard:lead" alternative-text="Lead" title="Leade">
</lightning-icon>
```

Resource:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon
- https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/